# Nginx dynamic location configuration

Tags: nginx

My goal is to configure nginx to match locations dynamically like this:

```
http://www.domain.com/app-one
http://www.domain.com/app-two
http://www.domain.com/app-three

/usr/share/nginx/html/app-one/public
/usr/share/nginx/html/app-two/public
/usr/share/nginx/html/app-three/public
```

I'm confused how to do this. And if I can do it like this or if it's recommended or best practice to do something like this (I don't want to go the subdomain solution).

If I'm trying this:

```
location ~ /(^/)+ {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/$1/public;
    index  index.html;
}
```

All I get is an 403.

But there's a way to handle that, right? Do you know how?

PS. Neither I found any explanation via google nor here that helps me.

Comment: You've missed semicolon

Comment: And regexp should be `^/([^/]+)`

Comment: Yeah, but only here ;) Doesn't change that 403.

Comment: And check the error.log. There should be mention of where nginx try to look for your files

Comment: Thanks for the regex correction. That pushed me a step ahead. And thanks for the advice to look in the error.log. Next I have to find a way how to rewrite the uri, couse nginx now looks at: 

    /usr/share/nginx/html/app-one/public/app-one/index.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
location ~ ^/([^/]+)(.*)$ {
    alias   /usr/share/nginx/html/$1/public$2;
    index  index.html;
}
```

Comment: Yep. That's it! Thank's a lot :)