# Nginx dynamic location path configuration

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Firstly I want to state that I'm rather new to nginx, I basically only know what I've learned over the last week.

That said, I currently have a Nginx server with a standard configuration of:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name site.com;

  root /var/www/site.com/;
  index index.php;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
  }

  location /microsite/first {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /microsite/first/;
  }

  location /microsite/second {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /microsite/second/;
  }

  ...
}
```

This works fine, although for every *microsite* I add to the existing ones, it requires that a new location be added referring to the path of the new *microsite*.

**My question is:** is it possible to dynamically set the `location` parameter in a way that it catches and references whatever sub-directory exists within the **microsite/** directory?

e.g. something along the line of the rewrite rule `rewrite ^(/download/.*)/media/(.*)\..*$ $1/mp3/$2.mp3 last;` (taken from the nginx site) but applied to the `location` parameter, like:

```
location ~ ^/microsite/(.*)$ {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /microsite/$1/;
}
```

In which the `$1` would catch the sub-directory name passed in `(.*)`?
*(I tried this snippet that I built refering to the answer to (another) [Nginx dynamic location configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37414123/nginx-dynamic-location-configuration) question, although it did not work)*

Also I'm not a Regex expert, I've tweaked a bit with it in the past but it was a while ago and I don't recall the precise terminology, so that may be part of the problem, perhaps?!

Anyway, all help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You probably need to limit the capture to the first two path segments:

```
location ~ ^(/microsite/[^/]+) {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $1/;
}
```

The `[^/]` character class matches anything that is not a `/`

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but it didn't work.

I tried the `location` block just like you wrote it, but when trying to access the site it just opens up the 'save file' window (downloading the *index.php* file, which we obviously do not want).

Comment: It needs to be placed after your `location ~ \.php$` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for how `nginx` processes a request. And you may want to make the last element explicitly link to `index.php` by using `$1/index.php`.

Comment: hey Richard, sorry for the absence but i got caught up in another project and just now got back to this issue. and i just want to thank you for you excellent help =) your suggestion did the trick.
although for what i understood from the _nginx_ documentation regarding `location` blocks prioritization, i though the more precise the path the `location` had configured, the higher it's priority as a server rule!!
although that block does have the `~` character before, so.. anyway, i put it after the `location ~ \.php$` block as you mentioned and it worked great, so thanks again =D cheers!!

Comment: Your understanding is correct for prefix locations, however, regular expression locations are evaluated in order until a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

Try something along the lines of:

```
location ~ ^/microsite/(?<foo>.+)$ {
    try_files $uri $uri/;
    root /microsite/$foo;
}
```

Comment: thank you also for your feedback, although unfortunately it also did not work.. the `location` block you shared returned a **500 Internal Server Error**. I played a bit with the code to see if I could get it to work, and found out that the 500 was caused by the `root /path/$foo` line.


I also tried putting the `$foo` variable on the `try_files $uri $uri/ /path/$foo` (with the `root ...` line commented out) and it just opens up the 'save file' window.